# Getting views inside BottomSheetDialogFragment from a RecyclerView adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I have a `RecyclerView`. Each cell of this `RecyclerView` view have a button that calls forth a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` from within an `Adapter`.

The bottom sheet does show up and dismiss correctly when calling it from my `Adapter`

I would like to be able to delete a cell by tapping a button inside my `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

Here is my button inside my `BottomSheetDialogFragment` class

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete" />
```

and here is my `onBindViewHolder()` where I can't find a way to access the deleteBtn from the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` so I can proceed with deleting my cell

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SavesAdapterHolder, position: Int) {
    val bottomSheet: BottomSheetDialogFragment = mBottomSheet()
    bottomSheet.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomDialogTheme)
    val myActivity = (context as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
    holder.openButton.setOnClickListener {
        bottomSheet.show(myActivity, "bottomSheet $position")

    }
}
```

Would anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction on how to access my delete button from inside my `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: wish [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198221/how-to-settext-button-in-bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment/61198602#61198602) can address your question to get the underlying views of the `BottomSheet`

Answer (score 0):

BottomSheet view should be accessible by ***getView()*** method

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SavesAdapterHolder, position: Int) {
    val bottomSheet: BottomSheetDialogFragment = mBottomSheet()
    bottomSheet.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomDialogTheme)
    val myActivity = (context as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
    holder.openButton.setOnClickListener {
        bottomSheet.show(myActivity, "bottomSheet $position")

       // execute the commited transaction before trying to access the view
        myActivity.executePendingTransactions()

      // accessing button view
        bottomSheet.view?.findViewById("*your_btn_id*").setOnClickListener{
             //you can remove item here and notify data set
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: bottomSheet.view? unfortunately returned null

Comment: edited the answer with executePendingTransactions call. Hopefully Should work. @PhilBlais