# How to append text in textview in bottom sheet from mainactivity?

Tags: android, textview, bottom-sheet

[my app screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMvwI.png)

I want to append text in textview on bottom sheet using MainActivity.

I have thread in my **MainActivity** to append text in textview.

I didn't about how to append the text from MainActivity  to bottom sheet.

I  want to append the text if the bottom sheet shown.

how can I do this ?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new Te()).start();
      
    Button OpenBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.open_bottom_sheet);

    OpenBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog();
                bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                                 "ModalBottomSheet");
            }
        });
}


private class Te implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
     
        // I want to append text in bottom sheet here

     }
   }
 } 


}
```

**BottomSheetDialog**

```
public class BottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable
                                                  ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle 
savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout,
                              container, false);

    TextView textapp = v.findViewById(R.id.algo_text);
    
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that from a thread; changing UI in android requires to be in the main thread; to modify the textView text in the bottom sheet; you can create a method that takes a String param, and just setText() inside of it. and call it from the activity `myBottomSheet.setTextViewText("some text")`

Comment: Because,  I want to make a socket connection and get messages from socket.  So , I need  to set the bottom sheet's `TextView` from MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**
> **Create a constructor and get the data as parameter**
> **pass it into another string**
> **then use setText**

```
//Activity

    public void onClick(View v)
                {
    //pass data to constructor as params
                    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog("pass your data here");
                    bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                                     "ModalBottomSheet");
                }

//BottomSheetDialog

public class BottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

//declare a string
String theName;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable
                                                  ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle 
savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout,
                              container, false);

    TextView textapp = v.findViewById(R.id.algo_text);

//setText here
    textapp.setText(theName); 
    
    return v;
}

//create constructor and pass parameters inside
public BottomSheetDialog (String name)
{
//assign 'name' to the String 'theName'
theName = name;
}

}
```

Comment: I want to append text infinitly using thread. Read my question.